# copy of List<T> on instanciation

Tags: c#, .net

In the following code why doesn't **y.e[0].k equal 20 instead of 30**?
What is obviously happening is that **y.e[0] = x.e[0]**

But what I need is to *copy* the List from x to y when y is instantiated, not just copy the pointer x.e to y.e;

However: **x.c is true** and **y.c is false** as I would expect.

Any helpful comments appreciated

```
class Eclass {
    public int k { get; set; }
    public Eclass(int iK) { k = iK; }
}

class Sclass {

    private static int ID = -1;
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool c { get; set; }
    public List<Eclass> e { get; set; }

    public Sclass() {
        c = false;
        Id = ++ID;
        e = new List<Eclass>();
    }

    public Sclass(Sclass org) {
        c = org.c;
        Id = ++ID;
        //foreach (var OrgE in org.e) { e.Add(OrgE); } //also doesn't work
        //e = org.e.ToList();
        e = new List<Eclass>(org.e);
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("steve");
        Eclass e1 = new Eclass(1);
        Eclass e2 = new Eclass(2);
        Eclass e3 = new Eclass(3);
        Eclass e4 = new Eclass(4);

        Sclass x = new Sclass();
        x.c = false;
        x.c = true;
        x.e.Add(e1);
        x.e.Add(e2);
        Sclass y = new Sclass(x);
        x.e.Add(e3);
        y.e.Add(e4);
        x.e[0].k = 10;
        y.e[0].k = 20;
        x.c = false;

        Debug.WriteLine("//{0}// //{1}// :: //{2}// //{3}//", x.c, x.e[0].k, y.c, y.e[0].k);
        x.c = !x.c;
        y.c = !y.c;
        x.e[0].k = 30;
        Debug.WriteLine("//{0}// //{1}// :: //{2}// //{3}//", x.c, x.e[0].k, y.c, y.e[0].k);
    }
}
```

> //False// //20// :: //True// //20//
>
> //True// //30// :: //False// //30//

Answer (score -1, accepted):

read the comments.  You will see the credit belongs to @EdPlunkett

```
class Eclass {
    public int k { get; set; }
    public Eclass(int iK) { k = iK; }
    public Eclass(Eclass org) { k = org.k; }
}

class Sclass {

    private static int ID = -1;
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool c { get; set; }
    public List<Eclass> e { get; set; }

    public Sclass() {
        c = false;
        Id = ++ID;
        e = new List<Eclass>();
    }

    public Sclass(Sclass org) {
        c = org.c;
        Id = ++ID;
        e = org.e.Select(ec => new Eclass(ec)).ToList();
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("steve");
        Eclass e1 = new Eclass(1);
        Eclass e2 = new Eclass(2);
        Eclass e3 = new Eclass(3);
        Eclass e4 = new Eclass(4);

        Sclass x = new Sclass();
        x.c = false;
        x.c = true;
        x.e.Add(e1);
        x.e.Add(e2);
        Sclass y = new Sclass(x);
        x.e.Add(e3);
        y.e.Add(e4);
        x.e[0].k = 10;
        y.e[0].k = 20;
        x.c = false;

        Debug.WriteLine("//{0}// //{1}// :: //{2}// //{3}//", x.c, x.e[0].k, y.c, y.e[0].k);
        x.c = !x.c;
        y.c = !y.c;
        x.e[0].k = 30;
        Debug.WriteLine("//{0}// //{1}// :: //{2}// //{3}//", x.c, x.e[0].k, y.c, y.e[0].k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as in the old days in C.  You want to make a copy of a structure?  Fine. But do you know if you want to copy the values of the structure or just the point to an instance of the structure at hand?  I'm glad I did some deep diving on this.  I was about to erroneously assume copy going to copy the values.

Answer (score 4):

You created `y` using the `Sclass` copy constructor:

```
Sclass y = new Sclass(x);
```

And the problem is this line in the `Sclass` copy constructor. That's where `y.e` came from:

```
e = org.e.ToList();
```

That creates a copy of `org.e` -- a new `List<Eclass>`, that has references to the original items in the old one. Therefore, `x.e[0]` is the same object as `y.e[0]`. You then give `y.e` and `x.e` each one additional item after `e2`, but you never look at those.

Because `Eclass` is a reference type rather than a value type, you need to explicitly make copies of each `Eclass` instance in the list, not just a copy of the list itself. If you change `Eclass` from a `class` to a `struct`, copies will be made automagically, because then it won't be a reference type. Then you should see the semantics you expected. `Eclass` would behave like `int k`: Assignment would create a new copy of the value, not a new reference to the old object.

The more usual way to do this, however, would be to give `Eclass` a clone method which returns a new, identical copy of `Eclass` -- or give it a copy constructor, much like the one for `Sclass`. I like copy constructors better than `Clone()` because the .NET framework tends to use them more, and in this case you've already got one for `Sclass`. Keep it consistent.

```
public Eclass {
    public Eclass() {}
    public Eclass(int k) {
        this.k = k;
    }
    public Eclass(Eclass org) {
        k = org.k;
    }
}
```

And in the Sclass copy constructor, copy e like so:

```
public Sclass(Sclass org) {
    c = org.c;
    Id = ++ID;

    //  For each item in org.e, create an identical copy, and then make a list of those. 
    e = org.e.Select(ec => new Eclass(ec)).ToList();
}
```

This is called a "deep copy": It makes a copy of the "root" object, and populates it with copies of all the reference type objects it refers to as well.

What you're doing now is a "shallow copy".

Comment: But for some reason .ToList() is also failing.  I edited the originally posed code.  Even a foreach() on the list is not getting the job done.  .Add() is just copying the memory address of OrgE to the list.  For every x.e a new e isn't being instantiated end x.e is copied to y.e. ~  OH.  Hold on you are adding even more I haven't read yet.

Comment: @Steve Can you show me your new version of the code? I don't understand what you're describing at all.

Comment: Dang.  You win again.  Just one note.  I gave e3 to 'x' and e4 to y.  And when I intellisense this x has 3 e(s) and y has 3 too.

Comment: I will post the final version.  But your use of LINQ did the trick which makes sense that it would.

Comment: Right, sorry, I didn't realize I was editing faster than you could read. Sounds like we're on the same page.

Comment: There you are. Thx